# random coloring of vertices of a tournament

Tags: graph-theory, probabilistic-method

I am taking a course on probabilistic methods in combinatorics. I couldn't solve the following exrcise:
Prove that for any tournament $T=(V, E)$ in which all outdegrees are at least 10, we can color the vertices so that every vertex at least one outneighbor of each color.

If I just color all vertices randomly, then the bound on the probability of the required property not holding is:
$$Pr(\exists v\in V \text{ all of $v$'s outneighbors are of the same color}) \\\le \sum_{v \in V}Pr(\text{all of $v$'s outneighbors are of the same color}) \\= \sum_{v \in V}(\frac{1}{2})^{\deg_{\mathrm{out}}(v) - 1} \le \sum_{v \in V}(\frac{1}{2})^{10} = n(\frac{1}{2})^{10}.$$

And this bound is not less than 1 for large $n$.
I know that I have not used the fact that $T$ is tournament, and I need to use it somehow.

My idea was to take two vertices $a, b \in V$ with large indegrees, color them by two different colors, and then every vertex who is connected to both will necessarily have outneighbors of both colors. But then I still have to worry about $a, b$ and all of their outneighbors.

I am thinking maybe there is some property of tournaments which I could use but don't know.

A probabilistic argument would be very appreciated, but just a graph-theoretic one would help as well.

Also, I am not looking for a full solution but rather for a hint, or some direction for this problem, since I really don't know where to even begin.

Comment: I don't think this makes much difference, but shouldn't your $n(\frac12)^{10}$ be $n(\frac12)^{10-1}?$

Comment: Note that there are at most $21$ vertices of outdegree $10,$ after that the outdegrees start to go up.  That could be useful.

Comment: Let $s_1\le s_2\le\cdots\le s_n$ be the outdegrees in increasing order. Note that $s_2\ge1,\ s_4\ge2,$ and in general $s_{2i}\ge i$ for all $i.$ In addition we are given that $s_1\ge10.$

Comment: By my hasty calculation, minimum outdegree $\ge5$ should be good enough for what you want.

Comment: Could you elaborate how you got these bounds?

Comment: Do you see why $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_n=\binom n2$? And likewise $s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_i\ge\binom i2$ for every $i\le n?$

Comment: Oh right. Great, I understand now!

Comment: I get those inequalities but can't seem to understand how to use them to get the required result, in particular I don't see how to use the $s_1 \geq 10$ assumption. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Port I have posted a detailed answer.

Comment: @user91015 I have posted a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem.** Let *T* be a tournament of order $n$ in which all outdegrees are $\ge5;$ then the vertices can be colored with two colors so that every vertex has at least one outneighbor of each color.

**Proof.** Let $p$ be the probability that a random $2$-coloring of the vertices fails to have the desired property; it will suffice to show that $p\lt1.$

Let $s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n$ be the outdegree sequence. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $$s_1\le s_2\le\cdots\le s_n.$$ Then, for each $i,$ we have
$$\binom i2\le s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_i\le is_i,$$
whence
$$s_i\ge\left\lceil\frac{\binom i2}i\right\rceil=\left\lceil\frac{i-1}2\right\rceil.$$
Thus we have
$$p\ \le\ \sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac12\right)^{s_i-1}\lt\ \ \sum_{i=1}^9\left(\frac12\right)^4+\sum_{i=10}^\infty\left(\frac12\right)^{\left\lceil\frac{i-1}2\right\rceil-1}\ =\ \frac9{16}+\frac14\ \lt\ 1.$$